# Vaadin: Do I need to persist package.json and package-lock.json?

Tags: vaadin, package.json, vaadin23

When you build Vaadin it generates two files: package.json and package-lock.json.

Do I need to persist them in my VCS (Git in my case)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`package.json` contains the frontend / npm / JavaScript dependencies for your project. If you do not add any custom dependencies to it, it can (and will) be re-generated automatically based on `@NpmPackage` annotations in Java sources.

`package-lock.json` is the means to provide a reproducible build. If you remove that, then the next build of the project might use different versions of some dependencies. In the worst case, the new versions have some bugs or compatibility problems and your project will no longer work.

It is therefore recommended to keep at least `package-lock.json` in the repository. If you are doing that, then keeping `package.json` also makes sense, as they kind of go hand in hand.

There may be also an additional benefit of keeping `package.json` in the version control, if you have dependency scanner that can warn you about vulnerable dependencies such as dependabot in GitHub.