# Should I commit package-lock.json to version control in a Vaadin project?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin24

After upgrading a project to the latest Vaadin 24 version, I removed package-lock.json so that it is regenerated during the build. It wasn't, although the build was successfull and I could run the project without issues.

Has something changed regarding the persistence of npm-related files in Vaadin? In general, should I keep package.json, package-lock.json, and possible other generated files in my code repository of a Vaadin project, or Vaadin will take care of generating them every time? I remember previously the answer was to keep package-lock.json in version control, although it was generated.

Many thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vaadin: Do I need to persist package.json and package-lock.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75543883/vaadin-do-i-need-to-persist-package-json-and-package-lock-json)

Comment: @ollitietavainen Thanks. Yes kind of. I knew that. But then why didn't Vaadin build generate package-lock.json for me anymore? Is that expected or a bug?

Comment: It doesn't build it, if it doesn't need it. See dev bundle in the docs for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a package-lock.json, commit it, along with package.json. Regenerating the files every time will lead to potentially inconsistent builds (not to mention slowness). If you're using the [pre-compiled frontend bundle](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/configuration/development-mode#precompiled-bundle), you might not need the package configuration files at all.